# How to use Transform stream to validate data in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I want to pipe data from my readable stream to a writable stream but validate in between.

**In my case:**

- **Readable Stream:** http response as a stream (Axios.post response as a stream to be more specific)
- **Writable Stream:** AWS S3

Axios.post response comes in XML format. So, it means the readable stream will read chunks that represent XML. I transform each chunk to string and check if `<specificTag>` (opening) and `</specificTag>` closing is available. Both these checks will be done in different or arbitrary chunks.

If both opening/closing tags are OK then I have to transfer the chunk to Writable stream.

I am coding like:

```
let openTagFound: boolean: false;
let closingTagFound: boolean: false;
readableStream.pipe(this.validateStreamData()).pipe(writableStream);
```

I have also defined `_tranform` method for `validateStreamData()` like:

```
private validateStreamData(): Transform {
  let data = '', transformStream = new Transform();
  let openTagFound: boolean = false;
  let closingTagFound: boolean = false;
  try {
    transformStream._transform = function (chunk, _encoding, done) {
      // Keep chunk in memory
      data += chunk.toString();
      if(!openTagFound) {
        // Check whether openTag e.g <specificTag> is found, if yes
        openTagFound = true;
      }
      if(!closingTagFound) {
        // parse the chunk using parser
        // Check whether closingTag e.g </specificTag> is found, if yes
        closingTagFound = true;
      }
      // we are not writing anything out at this
      // time, only at end during _flush
      // so we don't need to call push
      done();
    };
    transformStream._flush = function (done) {
      if(openTagFound && closingTagFound) {
        this.push(data);
      }
      done();
    };
    return transformStream;
  } catch (ex) {
    this.logger.error(ex);
    transformStream.end();
    throw Error(ex);
  }
}
```

Now, you can see that I am using a variable `data` at:

```
// Keep chunk in memory
data += chunk.toString();
```

I want to get rid of this. I do not want to utilize memory explicitly. The final goal is to get data from `Axios.post` and transfer it to `AWS S3`, only if my validation succeeds. If not, then it should not write to S3.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, What I finally did is, let the pipe end and kept some flags to check whether it is valid or invalid and then `on('end')` callback, if flag says invalid explicitly destroyed destination object.